# I need to choose strings beginning with capital letters and possibly ending with lower case

Tags: python, uppercase, lowercase

I need to pick strings from a body of text in set beginning with upper case and ending with lower case. This can include one letter capital words and exclude longer strings with all letters capital, e.g. from this: "A", "AbA", "Ab", "b", "bA", "bbb", "AAA" I need to choose this: "A", "Ab". This doesn't work:

```
from nltk.books import *
up_low = {
    x 
    for x in text1
    if x[0].isupper() and x[1:].islower
    
}
```

Any tips would be highly appreciated, I've just started with python :)

Comment: you need to properly indent your code

Comment: They are used in Python to define a dictionary

Comment: Curly braces are used to define a dictionary, but you cannot create one with a function inside the curly braces.

Comment: @Mr.J What do you mean with "with a function inside"? And why are you talking about a dictionary? It's a set comprehension.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: @Mr.J: list comprehension => dictionary comprehension `dict = {key:value for (key,value) in dictonary.items()}`

Comment: @TomášSavčenko: if you want it to be a dictionary, what should the key be?

Comment: @Thomas Weller: My bad, it's supposed to be a set but your answer worked perfectly!

Comment: @Prune I added the text I am working with to my code, i.e. text1 from nltk.books; hopefully this helps

Comment: What about "ABc"? Your text is unclear, your examples don't have such a case, your code makes it look like you *don't* want it, and the answer you called "worked perfectly" assumes you *do* want it.

Comment: @Manuel: that's true. I only consider the last character. My algorithm does not check for "begins with any number of upper case letters" and "ends with any number of lower case letters"

Answer (score 0):

You can access the last character of a string with `text[-1]`.
As far as I understand you want:

- an upper case letter in the beginning. Always: `text[0].isupper()`
- Either, that's it (for the result `A`): `len(text) == 1`
- Or it ends in a lower case letter: `text[-1].islower()`

Final code:

```
texts = ["A", "AbA", "Ab", "b", "bA", "bbb", "AAA"]
for text in texts:
    if text[0].isupper() and (len(text) == 1 or text[-1].islower()):
        print(text)
```

Or, if you want the result to be a list:

```
texts = ["A", "AbA", "Ab", "b", "bA", "bbb", "AAA"]
result = [text for text in texts if text[0].isupper() and (len(text) == 1 or text[-1].islower())]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions. I'm putting it here to complement the answer from Thomas Weller.

In order to use them you need to import the regular expressions library:

```py
import re
```

I made a dictionary that uses a number as a key and the text as the value.

```
string_dict = {}
string_dict[0] = "A"
string_dict[1] = "AbA"
string_dict[2] = "Ab"
string_dict[3] = "b"
string_dict[4] = "bA"
string_dict[5] = "bbb"
string_dict[6] = "AAA"
```

If you just want to know if the text passed the conditions, then this can work:

```py
regexp = "^[A-Z][a-z]*$"
for key, text in string_dict.items():
    if re.search(regexp, text):
        print("Passed: " + text)
```

This will output:

```
Passed: A
Passed: Ab
```

If you would like to store the results in a list:

```py
regexp = "^[A-Z][a-z]*$"
results = []
for key, text in string_dict.items():
    if re.search(regexp, text):
        results.append(text)

print(results)
```

This will output:

```
['A', 'Ab']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression:

```
import re

text     = ["A", "AbA", "Ab", "b", "bA", "bbb", "AAA","ABa"]
selected = [t for t in text if re.match(r"^[A-Z](.*[a-z])?$",t)]

print(selected)
['A', 'Ab','ABa']
```

*Note: I added 'ABa' which meets you criteria as described but was a use case missing from the sample data (so would 'A3-5b').*

Comment: Hmm, as I commented under the question, I find their text unclear and their `x[1:].islower` rather looks like they *don't* want `'ABa'`...

Comment: Then again it also states that "This doesn't work" (without an indication of why)

Comment: Right, though I'd say the missing `()` (i.e., *calling* `islower`), is a more likely reason (and that one is clearly unintentional, whereas the `[1:]` looks intentional to me). Oh well, maybe the OP will eventually clarify.